# How can I get content of values under key images in YAML file from the shell

Tags: shell, yaml

YAML file like this:

```
http:
  Domain: {{ environment.domains.httpport }} 
  images:
    emas_fe_weex: 20170810-ed0b13f
    eweex_basic_manager: 20150109-e0fafa3
  replicaCount:
    xxxx: 1
  resources:
    {}
```

How can I get the following with shell?

```
emas_fe_weex: 20170810-ed0b13f
eweex_basic_manager: 20150109-e0fafa3
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

It is best to process YAML with a YAML parser e.g. with Python and `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package). With the input in `input.yaml`:

```
< input.yaml python -c "import sys, ruamel.yaml; yaml=ruamel.yaml.YAML(); yaml.dump(yaml.load(sys.stdin)['http']['images'], sys.stdout)"
```

will output:

```
emas_fe_weex: 20170810-ed0b13f
eweex_basic_manager: 20150109-e0fafa3
```

Comment: By using the package in this way, the order of the keys in the extracted part is the same as in the original YAML.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Anthon: YAML is sufficiently complicated to require use of a YAML parser (like XML, JSON, CSV, etc)

Here are a few examples with other scripting languages, depending on your taste:

1. Ruby

   ```
   ruby -ryaml -e '
       data = YAML.load($stdin)
       puts YAML.dump(data["http"]["images"])
   ' < file.yaml
   ```
2. Perl (requires YAML::XS from CPAN)

   ```
   perl -MYAML::XS -0777 -nE '
       $data = Load($_);
       say Dump($data->{http}{images})
   '  < file.yaml
   ```
3. Tcl (requires tcllib)

   ```
   echo '
       package require yaml
       set data [yaml::yaml2dict -file "file.yaml"]
       puts [yaml::dict2yaml [dict get $data http images]]
   ' | tclsh
   ```

Comment: `ruamel.yaml` explicitly preserves the order of the keys when used in the way of my answer. If you know, can you indicate for these samples whether they do that; or if the keys in the output are sorted (as PyYAML would do) or that the keys may be  randomized? I am not sure if they sortedness of the input the OP presents is just coincidence, nor do we know if the order in the output is significant.

Comment: I don't know. The ruby and perl libraries are both documented to use libyaml, so whatever that does. Tcl, I don't know how the parser is implemented, but the dict datatype does preserve insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a system where `grep` is available, you can get them both with it. Assuming the data is in a file called `http.yaml`:

```
grep -e emas_fe_weex -e eweex_basic_manager http.yaml
```